# Unhandled exception in web application and forms authentication failing afterwards asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I m trying to troubleshoot random logouts in my web application. The forms authentication cookies is set to expire in 30min with sliding expiration. I m going through application event logs on webserver and found one of the users form authentication failing after 10 min but in between these ten min there were four unhandled exceptions logged. Just wondering if unhandled exceptions could cause authentication to fail?

Comment: What were those exceptions??

Comment: one of the exceptions is "Exception type: ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
"